# How can I make a section expandable?

Tags: html, css, web

Here is the site that I'm working on: http://viewsharer.com/

At the bottom of the page there is a contact us form, with a textbox for some comment. When the comment box is dragged out more, the box comes off of the blue section and so does the submit button.

Heres an image:

http://prntscr.com/35lhux

here the Let's Talk button is pushed down and covers the copyright!

Is there a way to tell the blue section to expand when the comment box expands so everything stays within the section? Thanks!

If you want to view the html/css you can rightclick the website and click view page source :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `height` from the `#contact` div, and give the `#submit` button a `margin-bottom: 48px;`

Comment: Yea. Sorry I'm new to html and css, I'm so stupid x(